# SSRS Grouping & Paging

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I'm trying to build a report in SSRS that has a few different report items displayed (text box, tables, etc) and needs to repeat on a new page per salesman. I'm fairly new to SSRS and have only really built reports that have a single matrix. See attached mockup. How can I accomplish this? I know how to do pagebreaks on a matrix, but how can I do this for all items on the report? Also, how can I make sure that the person that's displayed in the text box matches up with what's displayed in both tables? Each page should only display info applicable to that sales person. The textbox shows the name, region plus other misc details for that sales person. Both tables show details for that salesperson (list of their customers and sales details). Everything I've seen online only shows how to do page breaks within a table and does not show how to accomplish the same thing for everything in the view. Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help would be appreciated!

[image: Mockup]

Comment: can you show us the report design with the grouping etc? If you include all of the above inside the same group (sales person) then it should be fine.

Comment: I think the easiest would be to have a master report grouped by sales person with the sales person details and then two sub reports inside the same group for customers and sales details. This should achieve what you are looking for

Comment: I would just use a List box grouped by Sales Persons and a rectangle inside that with the text box and tables you need as in your pic. The List will generate a separate page for each salesperson.

Comment: All the above suggestions will work. Personally I would create a report that handles just one salesperson that looks like your sample above and use this as a subreport, create a master report to call it for each salesperson. I just find this easier to manage especially if the data for a single sales person is likely to be spread across more than one page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!! It seems that Lists was exactly what I needed (I thought this did something else based on the name). @AlanSchofield I'm interested in your answer and would like to learn more just to improve my overall skills. I think I know what you mean, but would you be able to elaborate a little more or point me to a resource so I can follow up? More specifically, how would the master report be setup? I'm picturing an "empty" container with 3 subreports (based on my example above).

Comment: I'll try to put togther an exmaple over the next few days.